# Float a table* above twocolumn text but below chapter in book class

Tags: floats, two-column, chapter-page

Pretty much the title. I have a feeling this isn't possible, but I feel like its worth asking. I had been using multicols to switch back and forth, allowing me to put the table beneath the chapter heading easily, but i really needed the ability to use floats, so I am seeking a different solution.

For clarification, its a \twocolumn layout in the book document class (using xelatex, if that matters), and it would need to be able to be different in each chapter so titletormat won't work (as far as I can figure, anyway). Below is a screenshot of it working in multicols, which I am trying to recreate.

[image: An image of it working with multicols]

Comment: I'm afraid my crystal ball is a low-end model which can't deduce your code from your question. I don't see any table in the image, so that's a bit puzzling, too. (My crystal ball gives 90% odds it isn't shown and 10% odds it's the epigraph.) Aside from that it suggests this is an XY problem. Why do you want to use a float? The essence of floats is that they float to a position determined by an algorithm. If you want something in a specific place, relative to other document elements, you don't want a float. Hence, you presumably want something else, but it is impossible (for me) to guess what.

Comment: sorry, yes, its the epigraph, its formatted in a table. I can definitely give a MWE, but its literally just a chapter heading, a table, and two columns of text, so I didn't expect it would be needed, sorry. As for why the float, its basically the only way I can think of to get it where I want it :D. I am totally open to other (better) solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you do not want a float (`figure*`) at all, but rather incorporate an image in the chapter heading, something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \centering
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge {\bfseries  #1}\par\nobreak
% new
\if!\chapteropen!%
\vskip 40\p@
\else
    \vskip 20\p@
\large
\chapteropen
    \vskip 30\p@
\fi
  }}
\newcommand\chapteropen{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\chapteropen{%
\includegraphics[width=25pt, height=14pt]{example-image-duck}%
\qquad
\textit{something about something}%
\qquad
\includegraphics[width=25pt, height=14pt]{example-image-duck}%
}
\chapter*{Some Chapter}

This \setcounter{enumi}{0}\loop\roman{enumi}, \stepcounter{enumi}\ifnum\value{enumi}<1000 \repeat

This \loop\roman{enumi}, \stepcounter{enumi} \ifnum\value{enumi}<100 \repeat

\renewcommand\chapteropen{%
\includegraphics[width=25pt, height=14pt]{example-image-a}%
\qquad
\textit{a different quote}%
\qquad
\includegraphics[width=25pt, height=14pt]{example-image-b}%
}
\chapter*{AnotherChapter}


This \setcounter{enumi}{0}\loop\roman{enumi}, \stepcounter{enumi}\ifnum\value{enumi}<1000 \repeat

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out in just a bit, but that does look like what I wanted! I had a feeling I was doing it wrong, but couldn't figure out how to do the different text in different chapters! Once I plug this in and tweak to me needs, I'll check back.

Comment: @JasonMurray I just did an inline `\renewcommand` version here. Probably in a real document I would hide it in a custom chapter macro, also if the ornaments are always the same they could be part of the command not added each time, so you only needed to give the text. it all depends.

Comment: Yeah, this just about has what I want, but it seems to only work with chapter*? I'm pretty sure I can tweak it from here to get what I want otherwise! Thank you so much!

Comment: @JasonMurray I copied `\@makeschapterhead` from book.cls and added the extra block, that's the star form, you could do the same with `\@makechapterhead` (with no `s`)

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it right up! thanks!